# ASP.NET Display name instead of id in dropdownlinst.

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Context:**

I have a database with multiples tables that have relationships for example
table [users] have id,name,type,password. and table [buildings] have id,name,location.and table [floors] have id,name,user_id,building_id.

**Question:**

I want to make 2 Dropdownlists one will display the name of the user and the other building name instead of user_id,building_id while still insert their ids into the database when the user click the insert button.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You got any code you wanna show us there fella?

Comment: Are you using MVC or Web Form?

Comment: Whether MVC or Webforms, the *developer* specifies which fields are used as keys and which as display values during binding. That's explained in all data binding tutorials for any ASP.NET stack. Without your code it's impossible to guess what could have gone wrong. Perhaps the database query returned only IDs? Or only the ID column is bound?

Comment: Your question is actually not a question, but a task.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should place user_id in value attribute of drop-down *option* tag if you are using html or razor and place user_name between *option* html tags like this:

in case of users:

```
<select>
  <option value="user.Id">user.Name</option>
</select>
```

in case of buildings:

```
<select>
 <option value="building.Id">building.Name</option>
</select>
```

of course you should put *option* tags in *foreach* loop.
hope this pseudo code gives you some idea